# Pipe "bad address" on pipe open

Tags: c, linux, pipe, posix, ipc

So, im trying to start a webserver that uses pipes to comunicate between process.

I was thinking to make a struct named `ctx` to send other info also.

My code looks like this:

**webserver.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    int pipefd[2];
} ctx_t;
```

**webserver.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ctx_t *ctx = {0};
    if(pipe(ctx->pipefd) == -1){
        perror("ctx pipe error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Output:** "ctx pipe error: Bad address"

if instead i declare my program like this, i have no error and the programs continue

**webserver.h**

```
int pipefd[2];
```

**webserver.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(pipe(pipefd) == -1){
        perror("ctx pipe error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Any ideas why i cant open the pipe inside a struct? I still havn't made any forks in the main program.

Thanks.

Comment: You're passing a null pointer to a function (system call) `pipe()` that doesn't accept null pointers.  Don't do that.

Comment: ctx is a pointer.  Its value is zero.  Referencing `ctx->pipefd` is bad.

Comment: You probably meant `ctx_t ctx[] = {0}` instead of `ctx_t *ctx ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell — you'd probably get warnings from the compiler about insufficient braces in the initializer — you'd need something like `ctx_t ctx[] = { { { 0, 0 } } };` to be fully braced (outer braces for array, middle ones for the structure, inner ones for the array within the structure).

Comment: I know that `gcc` will take `{0}` and initialize the declared object to be all zero, but am not sure if that is a standard feature.

Comment: It is standard — fully-braced is not mandatory, but the explanation of how initializers work is rather complex (C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization, ¶13 onwards](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a null pointer to a function (system call) `pipe()` that doesn't accept null pointers.  Don't do that!

```
ctx_t *ctx = {0};
```

That sets `ctx` to a null pointer, albeit somewhat verbosely (the braces are not necessary, though they're not harmful).  You need to allocate the `ctx_t` structure somewhere before trying to use it.

Use:

```
cts_t ctx = { { 0, 0 } };
```

and:

```
if (pipe(ctx.pipefd) != 0)
    …report error etc…
```

Using `== -1` is also OK.